# How do I return a generic HttpResponse in .NET 5/Core?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I need a controller method to be able to return any kind of responses with arbitrary headers and content. Previously I've been creating and returning the [HttpResponseMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage%28v=vs.118%29.aspx), but I see that this have been changed in the new .NET. [There is a shim](http://www.strathweb.com/2015/01/migrating-asp-net-web-api-mvc-6-exploring-web-api-compatibility-shim/) I could use by referencing the old familiar classes, but I'd like to do this the .NET Core way (whatever that might be).

We have the [Microsoft.AspNet.Http.HttpResponse](http://docs.asp.net/projects/api/en/latest/autoapi/Microsoft/AspNet/Http/HttpResponse/index.html?highlight=httpresponse), but that's abstract.
I tried to have the controller return a string and thus triggering the plaintext formatter, but the problem is then that it overwrites the ContentType header.

Is there a recommended way to do this in .NET Core?

Comment: Presuming your question relates to ASP.NET Core MVC (aka MVC 6) rather than ASP.NET Core? Reason I ask is because in the latter you have full access to the response object in your middleware.

Comment: @ChrisPickford Ah yes, thanks. I updated the tags.

Comment: What's your use case? Do you explicitly need to write the response headers or just alter something like the `Content-type`?

Comment: @ChrisPickford This specific use case is a lightweight http-proxy that just relays requests and responses from other arbitrary resources. So I need to copy most headers the status code and content.

Comment: So why are you using MVC to create a proxy? This can be achieved using custom middleware. In fact, there already exists a library for this: https://github.com/aspnet/Proxy

Comment: @ChrisPickford I had no reason to think it would be a bad idea and it was simple and a fast way to solve the problem in the old environment. Thank you for the link, I'll check that out. I'm still interested if it's doable in MVC though, even if it would be just for peace of mind.